# Executing file with PowerShell from where batch file is ran

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am creating a batch file that when a user runs it a file included in the folder is unzipped.

So like this:

Downloaded_Folder
|  Batch.bat
|  ZippedFile.zip

Though when I run the powershell command to unzip the powershell is ran from System32.
I am also unsure where the user will be opening this folder from (Their downloads, or desktop, or documents?)

Here is what I have:

```
openfiles > NUL 2>&1 
if NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto NotAdmin 
echo Hello from elevated command prompt
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('foo.zip', 'bar'); }"
goto End 
:NotAdmin 
echo This command prompt is NOT ELEVATED 
pause
:End

pause
```

Comment: I suggest you write the entire thing in Powershell. Both batch and Powershell can identify the current folder.

Comment: Here is a quick example that i tested on my side for downloading and Unzipping File [Download-UnZipFile.bat](https://pastebin.com/naTnnf4Z)